# How to ignore part of link in Regex.Match?

Tags: regex, vb.net, visual-studio-2010, numbers, match

here is my core, i want to ignore part from this link...
like that

```
    Dim s As String = WebBrowser1.Document.Body.OuterHtml

    'mesagge.Text = s

    Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(s, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "/profile_redirector/[ingnore-that]" & Chr(34) & ">(.*?)</a>")
```

links are like that: `<a href="/profile_redirector/110159529273744317851?gl=RO&amp;client=mv-google&amp;guid=&amp;hl=en-GB">Jerry Trafny</a>`and i want to extract Jerry Trafny

Thanks !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [Groups](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.text.regularexpressions.match.groups%28v=vs.110%29.aspx?cs-save-lang=1&cs-lang=vb#code-snippet-1) property for getting your relevant part of the link directly:

```
Dim m As Match = Regex.Match(s, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "/profile_redirector/[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ">(.*?)</a>")
Console.WriteLine(m.Groups(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace `[ingnore-that]` with `[^"]*`. So for your code it will be:

```
Dim match As Match = Regex.Match(s, "<a href=" & Chr(34) & "/profile_redirector/[^" & Chr(34) & "]*" & Chr(34) & ">(.*?)</a>")
```

Comment: is ok but the script extract all the link like that <A href="/profile_redirector/117647790048384800450?hl=en-GB&amp;gl=RO&amp;guid=&amp;client=mv-google">swan micmac</A> and i need only the swan micmac

Comment: @Malasuerte94 keep something unique around from `swan micmac` in your regex so that it only pick this one.